# What is the difference of SO_PATH and MODULE_PATH when in loading of OpenSSL Engine?

Tags: openssl, pkcs#11

When trying to load an engine to openssl with the following command

```
openSSL> engine -t dynamic -pre\ SO_PATH:/usr/lib/engines/engine_pkcs11.so \
-pre ID:pkcs11 -pre\ LIST_ADD:1 -pre LOAD -pre \
MODULE_PATH:/usr/lib/libcs_pkcs11_R2.so
```

we must especify path to two shared objects,**engine** and **module**, Can anyone tell me what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

`SO_PATH` tells OpenSSL where to find the engine.

`MODULE_PATH` is an engine-specific control that tells some engines where to find the module that they depend on. Basically, it's up to the engine to either execute the commands given it directly, or, in the case where third-party software is involved, pass them onto the third-party software, in which case the engine acts as a wrapper for the third-party module. It's up to the engine to figure out where this module is and load it, but some, like [libp11](https://github.com/OpenSC/libp11), make this configurable through the `MODULE_PATH` control.